# How to develop a pre-loader for a SharePoint 2010 site that works seamlessly with JSOM Script and jQuery Document Ready?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using a CEWP w/ HTML, CSS, jQuery, and JSOM on a SharePoint 2010 Team Site to develop tabbed content. In each tab I also have some "accordion" type functionality. The first tab is supposed to be a News-like tool that retrieves list items from a Custom List App on the current site.

The problem is, anytime I use the following function:
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionName, "sp.js");
it causes a delay in that portion of the page loading and it looks klunky when it loads. I have attempted to use:
    $(document).ready(function(){});
to establish a pre-loader and starts when the page loads, so that there isn't just white space there. And then when functionName() is executed, the pre-loader fades out and the content fades in. I thought this would work, however, This causes a strict timing of events to occur that isn't based on the JSOM script being ready.

I guess what I am really looking with help for is how to use the
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionName, "sp.js");
on SharePoint pages with JSOM and create smooth content retrieval.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want help you will need to provide people with the information that they need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `$(document).ready` in tandem with `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` since, as you noted, you lose control of the order of execution.

#### Embedding a Loading Message

One option that works reasonably well is to embed a loading image and/or message directly in the HTML, and only replace it or remove it when the script finally loads.

```
<div id="CustomContent">
    <div id="CustomPlaceholder">
        <img src="/_layouts/images/loading16.gif" /> Retrieving Content...
    </div>
</div>

<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
    function(){
        $("#CustomPlaceholder").remove();
        functionName();
    },"sp.js");
</script>
```

SharePoint comes with a number of animated loading images that you can find in the `/_layouts/images` directory, such as `loading.gif`,`loading16.gif`,and `progress.gif`

#### Alternatives to JSOM

**REST**: If you still find yourself frustrated by the delay from loading `sp.js` you could consider using the REST web services instead of the JSOM. You can make REST calls to retrieve info from SharePoint without waiting for any libraries to load (you don't even need jQuery if you're willing to use [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#request)).

**SOAP**: You can also tap into the [SOAP-based web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx) that SharePoint provides.

**SPServices**: The relatively popular 3rd-party SPServices library uses SharePoint's SOAP-based web services to provide functionality similar to the JSOM, with friendly wrapper objects that might be easier to work with than REST, depending on your comfort level. In general I prefer to work with JSOM over SPServices, but that's because I like to avoid extra libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried something similar but could not get it to work right, I think because I was really hanging on to $(document).ready() for some unknown reason.  I'm going to give this a try!